# Symfony can changing the 'secret' parameter break anything?

Tags: php, symfony, security, parameters

In the **parameters.yml** file there is a parameter named **secret** which defaults to `ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt` but it should be changed to something else.

What happens if the value of this parameter is changed in production? Can it break anything?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does not break anything. Changing the value **secret** parameter from time to time is even considered a good practice, suggested by the official documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#secret

The only thing to be aware of is:

> However, keep in mind that changing this value will invalidate all
>   signed URIs and Remember Me cookies. That's why, after changing this
>   value, you should regenerate the application cache and log out all the
>   application users.